# Instant search using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, search, instant

I have a query that works and runs well but I want to show all of my items before searching for a specific one. When I click the search btn without inputting anything in it shows all of my items, I want to show them without needing to press the search btn.

```
include_once('includes/db_connect.inc.php');
$output = '';
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $searchq = $_POST['search'];
    $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i", "", $searchq);
    $sql_search = "SELECT * FROM teams WHERE teamnum LIKE '%$searchq%'";
    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql_search) or die("Could not search!");
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if ($count == 0) {
        $output = 'No search results';

    } else {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

            $output .= "<a href='view-team.php?id={$row['id']}'><div class='match-child'>
            <div class='flex-inside-list'>
                <div class='alliance-vs'>
                <span>" . $row["teamnum"] ."</span>
                </div>
            </div></a>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you looking for an _autocomplete_ where it makes an AJAX request to search as you type, and returns the current matches in a little dropdownlist just under the search box (rather like on google where it suggests search words)?

Comment: *I want to show them without needing to press the search btn.* So create the page with all the data already included? I either don't understand your question of you're thinking too hard ;-)

Comment: Or are you saying you just want to have a static list of all your items shown when the page is first displayed? If so, what would then be the point of a search?

Comment: What you are looking for is the `onchange=""` attribute at your text input then do an ajax to your php page that gets all items

Answer (score 0):

If it's the same page, then just delete the `if(isset($_POST['search']))` because the code below obviously only gets executed when the if statement is true.

But then you will have to create a workaround for the button, to work again.

I recommend using ajax, if something should be printed on the same page over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using query concatenation. First fetch all records and then check is $search is empty or not? if not then concate the previous query. At last send the data in to view/HTML file.